# Can Python's argparse replace a single option by a group of options?

Tags: python, argparse

Some Linux commands provide a single option that is equivalent to a given group of options, for convenience. For example, rsync has an option -a which is equivalent to -rlptgoD. For a Python script, is it possible to implement this behaviour using argparse? Or should I just pass the -a option to my code and handle it there?

Comment: There's no built in mechanism to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` has been around long enough that it (or many implementations) probably uses `getopt` for parsing the commands (if it doesn't do its own parsing).  Python has a version of `getopt`.  Neither the `c` version or the `python` has a mechanism for replacing a `-a` command with `-rlptgoD`.  Any such replacement is performed after parsing.

The primary purpose of a parser is to decode what the user wants.  Acting on that information is the responsibility of your code.

I can imagine writing a custom `Action` class that would set multiple attributes at once.  But it wouldn't save any coding work.  It would look a lot like a equivalent function that is used after parsing.

Comment: OK, thank you.

I was hoping for a mechanism whereby the parser simply replaced -a by -rlptgoD _before_ parsing -r etc. That way, if we later want to change the parsing of -r (eg to change the name of the corresponding attribute) we only have to make the change in one place. On the other hand if we're doing the work after parsing or using a custom `Action` class then we have to make the change there as well. So be it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, then edit `sys.argv` before calling `parse_args`.  And indirectly there's the `fromfile_prefix_chars` mechanism for reading argument strings from a file.  That can replace a `@a` with `-rletap` or more.